# List of all (integer) constants for various types

Tags: debugging, constants

Does there exist some kind of service, where I can input a system "enum type" (or similar) and get a list of all the possible values?

When debugging with gdb and you encounter an error, it would be nice to quickly get the name of the error, without having to look through related headers files of the header file where the type is defined.

For example the type `kern_return_t` in OS X is defined in `/usr/include/mach/i386/kern_return.h` which basically only contains one line of content (no includes):

```
typedef int     kern_return_t;
```

The valid values are defined in `/usr/include/mach/kern_return.h`, which makes sense, but I can never remember this path and I would like to speed up this process.

**Example:**

Input: `kern_return_t`

Output:

```
0 | KERN_SUCCESS
1 | KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS
2 | KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE
3 | KERN_NO_SPACE
4 | KERN_INVALID_ARGUMENT
5 | KERN_FAILURE
6 | KERN_RESOURCE_SHORTAGE
7 | KERN_NOT_RECEIVER
8 | KERN_NO_ACCESS
9 | KERN_MEMORY_FAILURE
...
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what `open -h` was made for. I recommend combining it with `-s` however, like so:

```
$ open -s iOS -h kern_return
kern_return?
[0] cancel
[1] all

[2] /usr/include/mach/i386/kern_return.h
[3] /usr/include/mach/kern_return.h
[4] /usr/include/mach/machine/kern_return.h
[5] /System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Headers/mach/i386/kern_return.h
[6] /System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Headers/mach/kern_return.h
[7] /System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Headers/mach/machine/kern_return.h

Which header(s) for "kern_return"?
```